# Aligning the left most character of each value in a column

Tags: c++, alignment, setw

For a lab of mine we need to display the output values in a column following a statement of what the value is for.

Example of what I need.

```
Amount of adult tickets:                      16
Amount of children tickets:                   12
Revenue from ticket sales:                    $140.22
```

I am trying to use setw like

```
cout << "Amount of adult tickets: " << setw(15) << ticketsAdult` << endl;
cout << "Amount of children tickets: " << setw(15) < ticketsChildren << endl;
```

I'm assuming either setw is the wrong thing to use for this or I'm using it wrong as it usually results in something like

```
Amount of adult tickets:                    16
Amount of children tickets:                    12
```

What can I use to make the values to the right all align like they did in the example no matter the length of the "Amount of..." statements before each of them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765155/how-can-i-easily-format-my-data-table-in-c

Comment: Use `std::setw` on the strings, not the values. Closing as typo.

Comment: See the justification modifiers, [std::left, std::right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is right and left alignment too. Other than that it looks like it's a pain to use.

[C++ iomanip Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424332/c-iomanip-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

Combining everything said together

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int ticketsAdult = 16;
    int ticketsChildren = 12;
    double rev =140.22;
    std::cout << std::setw(35) << std::left << "Amount of adult tickets: " <<  ticketsAdult <<  '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(35) << std::left << "Amount of children tickets: " <<   ticketsChildren <<  '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(35) << std::left << "Revenue from ticket sales: " <<   '$' << rev <<  '\n';
    return 0;
}
```